# Duplicate data through loop in r

Tags: r

I want to write a loop in `dplyr` where I want to duplicate the entire data with the name of the variable.

I have data in a datatable

```
# TABLE 1:
Names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")

# TABLE 2:
Cites         Area
Ahemdabad     Urban
Vadodara      Rural
Surat         Urban
Anand         Rural
```

I want an output like

```r
Names  Cites         Area
A      Ahemdabad     Urban
A      Vadodara      Rural
A      Surat         Urban
A      Anand         Rural
B      Ahemdabad     Urban
B      Vadodara      Rural
B      Surat         Urban
B      Anand         Rural
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
require(data.table)

for (i in namesX) 
    {
     require(dplyr)
     cities_final1<- cities_final%>%  
     select((i) as region,cities,area)
     group_by(region,cities,area) 
    }
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You really do not want or need to load `dplyr` each and every time in the loop; move that *outside* of the loop, do it once. Also, you're using it wrong: `require` does not error if a package load fails, it just warns *and keeps going*. So either use `library` (which does throw an error) or use `require` and check its return value and do something if it is false. (Really, in this case it's clearly better to use `library`. Clear to me, at least :-)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, you need to supply some sample data, and an expected result.

Comment: I have edited the question can someone help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your second table is a dataframe named `df`. You could use `tidyr`:

```r
crossing(Names, df)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 28 x 3
   Names Cites     Area 
   <chr> <chr>     <chr>
 1 A     Ahemdabad Urban
 2 A     Anand     Rural
 3 A     Surat     Urban
 4 A     Vadodara  Rural
 5 B     Ahemdabad Urban
 6 B     Anand     Rural
 7 B     Surat     Urban
 8 B     Vadodara  Rural
 9 C     Ahemdabad Urban
10 C     Anand     Rural
# ... with 18 more rows
```